# solve third order ode and find a error: Cannot feed value of shape (40,) for Tensor Placeholder_19:0, which has shape (None, 2)

Tags: autosuggest

code given the error: Cannot feed value of shape (40,) for Tensor Placeholder_19:0, which has shape (None, 2)

I am trying to do a code of solving third order ode system  and I am having some issues. Namely, I am getting the following error:
Cannot feed value of shape (40,) for Tensor Placeholder_19:0, which has shape (None, 2)